# Finding anagrams in a word list using Python

Tags: python, strings, python-3.x, file

```
##open file and create a dictionary of {"word":"sorted word"}

word_file = open("word_list(1).txt","r")
word_list = {}
for text in word_file:
    simple_text = ''.join(sorted(text.lower().strip()))
    word_list.update({text.lower().strip():simple_text})

##lowercase and sort the user input word
def simplify_entered_word():
    lower_word = ''.join(sorted(input_word.lower().strip())) #Creates a list with the lowercase, sorted letters.
    return lower_word

#Compare the sorted user input with the values of the dictionary to find the anagrams.
def find_in_dict(entered_word):
    for key,val in word_list.items():
        if val == entered_word:
            print(key,input_word)

##main loop

while True:
    input_word = input("Input the word for anagram checking: ")
    find_in_dict(simplify_entered_word())
```

Answer (score 5):

Good that you tagged with Python 3, as it *kinda* works in Python 2.7
with a bit different behaviour.

All the time reminder to format according to
[PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/); here I'd note that
there should be spaces between names, i.e. `key, val` and
`print(key, input_word)`.

Firstly, it's good that there are functions to split the logic up.
However part of that is negated by using globals.  In general using
globals is a bad pattern - here in particular it makes more sense to
pass the word list through to the individual functions.

**Edit**: And I forgot to update it to not use globals, shame on me ...

Most of the comments can also be docstrings instead.

---

Now, for the globals.  Just pass them through to the functions:

```python
def simplify_entered_word(input_word):
    "Lowercase and sort the user input word."
    word = input_word.lower().strip()
    return word, "".join(sorted(word))
```

This function can now also be reused easily by returning *two* results,
the lowercased word and the sorted result.

Next I'd move the word list reading its own function:

```python
def read_word_list(filename):
    """Open file and create a dictionary of {"word":"sorted word"}."""
    with open(filename, "r") as word_file:
        word_list = {}
        for text in word_file:
            word = text.lower().strip()
            simple_text = "".join(sorted(word))
            word_list.update({word: simple_text})
        return word_list
```

However this can also be much easier in terms of `simplify_entered_word`:

```python
def read_word_list(filename):
    """Open file and create a dictionary of {"word":"sorted word"}."""
    with open(filename, "r") as word_file:
        return {simple[0]: simple[1]
                for simple in map(simplify_entered_word, word_file)}
```

N.b. there might be a better way to write that dictionary
comprehension.  Note also that I used `with` as to not leak the file
handle from `open`.

And then call that with the filename:

```python
if __name__ == "__main__":
    word_list = read_word_list("word_list(1).txt")
    while True:
        input_word = input("Input the word for anagram checking: ")
        find_in_dict(word_list, simplify_entered_word(input_word)[1])
```

Just in case this will only run as a script and not if the file is
imported somewhere else, which is good practice.

One problem that still remains is the iteration in `find_in_dict`.  It'd
be much simpler if the data structure is slightly changed by collecting
all words for one anagram into a list:

```python
from collections import defaultdict

def read_word_list(filename):
    """Open file and create a dictionary of {"word":"sorted word"}."""
    with open(filename, "r") as word_file:
        word_list = defaultdict(list)
        for word, simplified in map(simplify_entered_word, word_file):
            word_list[simplified].append(word)
        return word_list

def find_in_dict(word_list, entered_word):
    """Compare the sorted user input with the values of the dictionary to find
    the anagrams."""
    for name in word_list.get(entered_word, []):
        print(name, entered_word)
```

Note the use of `defaultdict` to simplify the automatic creation of the
list.

Comment: "N.b. there might be a better way to write that dictionary comprehension." It's not using a comprehension at all, ;P
`dict(map(simplify_entered_word, word_file))`.
You change how you use the `dict` with the `defaultdict` addition, if you didn't you could use `defaultdict(int, map(lambda x: (x, x*2), range(10)))`.